# Nuxtjs - Authentication

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I wrote a sign up functionality in nuxtjs. It saves a new user in my database. However, there seems to be a problem with generating a token afterwards, to log in the user.
The register action gets called by a method in the register component. It returns the error response in the catch block. It seems to fail after the token is generated on the server.

**Action in the store**

```
async register ({ commit }, { name, slug, email, password }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.$axios.post('/users', { name, slug, email, password })
      commit('SET_USER', data)
    } catch (err) {
      commit('base/SET_ERROR', err.response, { root: true })
      throw err
    }
  }
```

**Post function on the nodejs server**

```
router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['name', 'slug', 'email', 'password']);
    const user = new User(body);
    await user.save();
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken(); // execution seems to fail on this line
    console.log(token); // never gets called
    req.session['token'] =  'Bearer ' + token;
    req.session['user'] =  user;
    res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Der Account konnte leider nicht erstellt werden" });
  }
});
```

**GenerateAuthToken function in mongo model User**

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
  var user = this;
  var access = 'auth';
  var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, process.env.JWT_SECRET).toString();

  user.tokens.push({access, token});

  return user.save().then(() => {
    return token;
  });
};
```

**Error message**
[image]

I would be tremendously thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: You'll want to find out what `err` is in your `/users` route. Even adding `console.error(err)` before `res.status(400)` would help

Comment: You are sending a request to api/users but your router.post('/users') does not handle that, have you added the app.use('/api', router) line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't help too much, but I would try to create a dummy token and try to make everything works with it. One of my debugging techniques is to isolate every single part of my code and be sure that everything works piece for piece, maybe that technique is slow but most of the time it works.

If everything works, I would continue debugging the  *generateAuthToken* function.
If your console log never gets called, then the error could be in the function.

I hope it helps a little and sorry I don't know too much about MongoDB but everything seems to be ok.